# Why is it adding when it’s not being called

Tags: javascript, php, html, session, session-cookies

I made a JavaScript code that I’m building to make a shopping cart, but this code is run even if I don’t click it:

```js
function addProduct(prodId) {
  var sessionDivId = document.getElementById(prodId);
  if (prodId) {
    sessionDivId.innerHTML = '<?= $_SESSION['product_id_1']+=1 ?>';
  }
}
```

```html
<div onclick="addProduct('testSession1');">ADD</div>
<div id="testSession1"></div>
```

Everytime I refresh the website it adds `1` to session `testSession1` even if I don’t click the button “ADD”.

Comment: Don't forget that php executes before javascript so even though the javascript has not been executed in the browser, the server has already processed the php. In this case the server sees the call to add 1 to the session variable and so will add it. If you need to achieve this the best method would be to use ajax to call to a php script that adds to the session variable.

Comment: I never used ajax, I searched abit for it but people give too wide things when I only want something to start with so I can build it myself :) if you can provide something id be grateful

Comment: If you were to ignore ajax you could potentially get the javascript to submit a form to the same page and then test for POST - once you have a POST request then you could increment the session variable. ie: `if( $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' ) { /* increment session var */ }`

Comment: @J.Doe I think going through [this tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) will be a good start. There was a time when I also didn’t know anything about AJAX. Then, on a night where I couldn’t sleep, I asked myself “how does AJAX work?”, grabbed my phone and quickly learned it over night, so to speak. So, it’s really not that hard.

Comment: Thanks guys, I dont know if im in the mood to read up on it now, I guess I will just do it with hardcore php form and post requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your PHP logic will be run on the server before the user loads the page. To add a product, you will need to store it somehwere else (since the PHP has no longer any control to put +=1 to the cart).

I would make an AJAX request to post a product id to the user shopping cart:

```
function addProduct(prodId) {
    // using jQuery for simplicity of writing
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/cart/item/" + prodId,         // or other backend API endpoint
        success: displayNiceUserMessage()
    });
 }
```

And of course some error handling in case something goes wrong.

**Update**

I saw that you did not want to use Ajax. Just so you know, it doesn't need to be any more complex than the code I wrote above. Then in the backend you just add +1 to the session if any user makes a POST request to that url.

But if you do not want ajax, you will need to reload the page when clicking the add button. Like was said in the comments, put a form of type post around the add button (and with a good url to make your server know that it was an added item event that took place), and make the add button a submit type. Then no javascript is needed at all.

Comment: Thanks man, this worked perfectly! is there any possible way to have a realtime printer of the session id? like a showProduct ajax?

Comment: Yes, in the success function you can update the `document.getElementById(prodId).innerHTML` value with +1